# how to add facebook comments to a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, comments

i have a simple blog created in ruby on rails, my models include 
 post, categories and categorization. that is post belongs to many categories through categorization

post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :categorizations
   has_many :categories, through: :categorizations
  attr_accessible :author, :description, :title, :photo, :category_ids    
end
```

category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :posts, :through => :categorizations
end
```

categorization.rb

```
class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category_id, :position, :post_id
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :category
end
```

**No User Model** in the application
i want to be able to add a facebook comment to the post model so that anyone who visits my application can comment on any post, and also a way i can count the post with the highest facebook comment so i can make use of of it

Answer (score 4):

Read [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/)

You only need to include something like this on your app

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=504323752911178";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and `Place the code for your plugin wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page.`

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com" data-width="470" data-num-posts="2"></div>
```

where `data-href` is the url of your post

Comment: thanks for your answer, how do i test this in the developement environment??

Comment: thanks a lot it worked for me, but my question now is how do i count the number of comments for each post?

Comment: `<fb:comments-count href=http://example.com/></fb:comments-count> awesome comments` this will emmit `55137 awesome comments`

Answer (score 0):

You can have look at this gem, https://github.com/intridea/omniauth
You can do lot many things using this gem and you can store in your database.